# Performance issue when resizing Win32 containing WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winapi, interop, c++-cli

I am in the process of migrating an existing legacy project. For now we want to use C++/CLI as a bridge between business logic (native C++) and interface (WPF). I followed this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744829.aspx) on how to host WPF content in a Win32 window as a starting point. However, I cannot wrap my head around this problem: Whenever I resize the host window...

- There are serious delays and the window is repainting slowly.
- It causes the Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe) to increase dramatically in memory usage (2 GB in a few seconds of resizing)

I stripped down the code to its bare minimum. A simple, red WPF page and a normal Win32 project with little changes:

```
namespace ManagedCode {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::Windows::Interop;

    void Create(HWND parent) {
        HwndSource^ container = gcnew HwndSource(NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, NULL,
            0, 0, 100, 100, "WPFCONTENT", IntPtr(parent));
        Managed::WpfPage^ page = gcnew Managed::WpfPage();
        container->RootVisual = page;
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
...
    case WM_CREATE:
        ManagedCode::Create(hWnd);
...
}
```

This *has* to be something really stupid.

Comment: If the problem is during resize, can you post the code that handles the resize event?

Comment: There is no resize handler at the moment. Before i basically called `SetWindowPos(container handle, NULL, 0, 0, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), SWP_NOZORDER)` in WndProc on WM_SIZE but that didn't make it worse... or better.